# Pyjamas framework significance

Tags: python, pyjamas

I am learning Pyjamas framework of python to generate the frontend which is basically a javascript code generated by Pyjamas. Though, being a new concept and a GWT equivalent in python I am interested in learning it, but I can not really find out what is the actual significance of it? I mean we are coding in python, compiling the code and generating javascript, which allows us to put CSS classes with the code. So, basically it does not removes the need of a designer as well.

Also, is it a good idea to use Pyjamas with Django?

Please suggest.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GWT and Pyjamas were created to remove the drugery of coding Javascript and compensating for all of the different browser implementations and object models.

- Yes, you still need a designer.
- Yes, you can code in python and not
  have to learn Javascript (in theory).
- No, you won't have to recode to work 
  around "features" of the Javascript
  implementations in new browsers or
  old browsers.

Comment: Thanks Terrel. I usually work on Django framework for developing web applications and I am very confused in using Pyjamas with Django. I am not able to find out whether it should be used with Django or not because they both are so different that it does not seem to be a good deal(atleast to me).

Comment: Use pyjamas for client side, Django for server side. GWT actually gives you a choice - you can write once and deploy on either server or client (or both). http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hNEvr2eLad0

Comment: Interesting comment: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2007/09/18.html  maybe GWT is the NewSDK and Gmail won't be obsolete.